# How to avoid $(data) throwing "refused to execute inline event handler"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a small chrome extension that gets some html content from external sources (quite a few).

In order to extract the relevant information (just text), I use

```
var $response = $(data);
var $senderows = $response.find(".sendetermine tr");
$senderows.each(function() {
   ...
});
```

to scan the resulting HTML. I don't need to add the ajax result to the DOM, therefore I don't care about any of the inline scripts of the external HTML result. But still: Chrome keeps throwing hundreds of "Refused to execute inline event handler" errors. The errors are already appearing if I only use `var $response = $(data)`.

How can I get rid of them? How can I parse the resulting HTML (preferrably using jQuery) without getting those errors?

EDIT: Any other hints? Those errors are being thrown at a very high rate, they even slow down the browser noticeably

Comment: Have you tried using `$($.parseXML(data))`?

Comment: Yes, with the exact same result

Comment: But it was $.parseHTML ... because the ajax result is HTML rather than XML

Comment: Any other hints? Those errors are being thrown at a very high rate, they even slow down the browser noticeably

Answer (score 0):

At least I was able to find a workaround: I removed all the onXXXX inline handlers from the HTML text before using `$()` on it, et voilà, no more errors.

```
function removeInline(theHTML) {
   theHTML = theHTML.replace(/onclick=\"[^\"]*\"/g, '');
   theHTML = theHTML.replace(/onchange=\"[^\"]*\"/g, '');
   theHTML = theHTML.replace(/onsubmit=\"[^\"]*\"/g, '');
   theHTML = theHTML.replace(/onmouseover=\"[^\"]*\"/g, '');
   theHTML = theHTML.replace(/onmouseout=\"[^\"]*\"/g, '');
   theHTML = theHTML.replace(/onerror=\"[^\"]*\"/g, '');
   theHTML = theHTML.replace(/onload=\"[^\"]*\"/g, '');
   return theHTML;
}
```